# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'fname')

Tags: node.js, express, body-parser

[so this is from bootstrap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ivXt.png)

[And here everything looks ok, i mean i can't see the problem and that is why I can't solve it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/feZHM.png)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your POST route, which looks like this (by the way, please use text to display your code, not screenshots):

```
app.post("/", function (res, req) {
   // callback body
});
```

The `res` and `req` parameters are in reverse order. Change your POST route to look like this:

```
app.post("/", function (req, res) {
    // callback body
});
```